# Cannot register RADIUS server in Active Directory, Windows Server 2008 r2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, radius

I'm trying to set up a [RADIUS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RADIUS) server in Windows 2008 R2 following the guide *[Install Windows 2008 R2 NPS for RADIUS Authentication for Cisco Router Logins](http://aaronwalrath.wordpress.com/2010/06/22/install-windows-2008-r2-nps-for-radius-authentication-for-cisco-router-logins/)*.

What I can't do is to register the RADIUS server to the Active Directory service which is located on the same server (see screenshot). I've tried to do this as both domain administrator and local administrator.

How can I fix this problem?

[image: How it looks]

Comment: Try this from the command line.
netsh ras add registeredserver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
netsh ras add registeredserver
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also register `NPS` servers in `AD` using `ADUC` and adding computer account of the `NPS` server to the Members tab of `RAS and IAS Servers` Security Group.

See more ways to register the NPS Server in AD DS ( [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754878.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) ).